# Java - number to string numeral system

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to make my own numeral system( don't laugh ), let's say like this:
0 = Me, 1 = You, 2 = We, 3 = They, 4 = I ... and so on.
I want the input to be a number ( ex. 4210 ) and the output to be a String ( ex. IWEYOUME ).
I want to make it without using any methods and so on. I have this code so far:

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = input.nextInt();
    String numberStr = String.valueOf(num);
    char[] digit = numberStr.toCharArray();
    String numeralStr = "";
    for (char c : digit) {
        switch (c){
            case '0' : numeralStr = "Me";
                break;
            case '1' : numeralStr = "You";
                break;
            case '2' : numeralStr = "We";
                break;
            case '3' : numeralStr = "They";
                break;
            case '4' : numeralStr = "I";
                break;
            default: numeralStr = "Not a part from this numeral system.";
                break;
        }
        System.out.print(numeralStr);
    }
```

What do you think? Is it better to make it using a method ( for example if I want to have all the numbers form 0 - 9 ), or to leave it something like this?
Thank you!

P.S. This is one of my first Java programs so pleasse don't judge me too hard :)

Comment: Use a `Map` if possible. The number can be your `key` and `String`, your value. And frankly, this is too broad, *no specific question*

Comment: Hi, I know it's broad but I'm not really sure is this the right way to do it. Thank you for the advise to use a Map :)

Comment: Does it matter what we think? It matters more that a) the code does everything you need it to; b) you understand what the code does so you can change it when you need to. The code looks fine, generally. My *preference* would be to have the switch in a separate method (allowing you to have one fewer statement per case e.g. `case '0': return "Me";`, if you want), which is also easier to unit test, but it's mostly personal preference for code as simple as this.

Comment: Also why are you using `String.toCharArray()`? I suggest using `Integer.parseInt(String)` see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)). In-fact why do you parse it to string and thenback to int (character array)?

Comment: If you want a review of working code, codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you, you are right! :) My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

For your case it's better to use java.util.Map. Put appropriate association there. Then you don't have to write a long case list.

```
Map<String, String> charMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
//or <Integer, String> if you have Integer keys

charMap.put("0", "Me");
charMap.put("1", "You");
```

...

```
for (char c : digit) {
    String append = charMap.get(""+c); //or convert your char into String     before
    numeralStr += append!=null?append:"Not a part from this numeral system.";
}
System.out.print(numeralStr);
```